# sbt command not found

Tags: scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I am installing sbt in my cloudera distribution.

1. I have downloaded sbt.0.13.15
2. Moved file to /usr/local
3. Then I had updated profile
   sudo nano profile
   Added export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbt/bin
   Saved file and exited.
4. But now if I issue "**sbt about**" command, I am getting sbt: command not found.

Could you please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Check your PATH variable: `echo $PATH`
- The PATH variable is not updated automatically by writing into .profile, either open a new shell or do `source .profile`
- The file is called .profile, not profile